# flutter dynamic Checkboxes don't check

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

Hi im new to Flutter and coding and tried do build my first to do app. I've created a textformfield to add new todos with a button in a container above. By pressing a button, a new todo will appear on the todo Container. I managed to dynamically give a column new todos with a CheckboxListtTitle. However, when adding a new todo, the todo with a checkbox appears but can't be checked. What did I do wrong here?

`to_do_section.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/responsive_layout.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

var toDoList = <String>[userInput];

class ToDos extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> list;
  const ToDos({
    Key? key,
    required this.list,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDos> createState() => _ToDosState();
}

class _ToDosState extends State<ToDos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    bool checked= false;
    bool? value_1;
    var isSelected = [false, false];

    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 10,
            left: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
            right: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
            bottom: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 8),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 40,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[400],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black45, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ToDoColumn(setState, checked),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  
  Column ToDoColumn(
      StateSetter setState, bool checked) {
        
    return Column(children: [
      for (final value in widget.list)
        CheckboxListTile(
          value: checked,
          onChanged: (_value_1) {
            setState(() {
              checked = _value_1!;
            });
          },
          title: Text('${value}'),
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          checkColor: Colors.black,
        )
    ]);
  }
}
```

`landing_page.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/presentation/widgets/to_do_section.dart';

 final _textController = TextEditingController();
    String userInput = "";
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text("To-Do-App")),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [ToDos(list: toDoList), ToDoAdd()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 

  Column ToDoAdd() {
    return Column(
          children:  [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => userInput = value) ,
                
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Add a new ToDo",
                )  ,
              ),
              
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                  toDoList.add(userInput);
                  
                });
                  
                },
                child: Text("Admit", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
                Text(userInput)
          ],
        );
  }


}
```

Comment: You initialize `bool checked= false;` on `build`, so everytime you check it and call `setState` then the `checked` value will be initialized to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable declared inside the build method will be redeclared on each build. You could move its declaration outside and assign a value in the `initState` method.

Also, the use of the `StatefulBuilder` is not justified in your code. You could simply use the StatefulWidget as it is.

I will take the model class from @yeasin-sheikh

```dart
class Task {
  final String text;
  final bool isChecked;

  Task({
    required this.text,
    this.isChecked = false,
  });

  Task copyWith({
    String? text,
    bool? isChecked,
  }) {
    return Task(
      text: text ?? this.text,
      isChecked: isChecked ?? this.isChecked,
    );
  }
}
```

This example is a reduced one that accomplish what you are trying to do. Please notice that I'm not reproducing your design. The function `addRandomToDo()` could be replaced with your code for adding Tasks to the app.

```dart
class ToDoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToDoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDoPage> createState() => _ToDoPageState();
}

class _ToDoPageState extends State<ToDoPage> {
  final tasks = <Task>[];

  void addRandomToDo() {
    setState(() {
      tasks.add(Task(text: 'Random ToDo ${tasks.length + 1}'));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ToDo App'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tasks.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              key: ObjectKey(tasks[index]),
              title: Text(tasks[index].text),
              value: tasks[index].isChecked,
              onChanged: (isChecked) {
                setState(() {
                  tasks[index] = tasks[index].copyWith(isChecked: isChecked);
                });
              },
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addRandomToDo,
        tooltip: 'Add ToDo',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tips:

- The use of Column for this example is not recommended. The best is to use a ListView.builder() and the reason is that when you use a Column and you have more element than the screen can render the app will also render the ones that are offscreen and will result in a lack of performance but the use of ListView will be best because it only renders a few elements offscreen (maybe two or three) to avoid a memory overload and it will load and render the elements as you scroll.
- Is a best practice to not use functions to return a piece of the screen but to split it into widgets. (Instead of having a ToDoColumn function just change it for a ToDoColumnWidget). The explanation for this is that will incurre in a lack of performance because all functions will be re-rendered on every widget build.
- This piece of code :

  `EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20)`
- Could be changed for this one:

  `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 20)`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined isSelected inside the build method. The build method is invoked each time you set the state. Please move it to initState.

```
  bool checked= false;
```

Define bool checked = false outside the build method or in initstate

Answer (score 1):

Putting variables inside `build` method will reset the bool and always be false. Also on your snippet you are just holding text without check state. On evey-build it will also reset on this point.

You can remove `StatefulBuilder` while this is already a `StatefulWidget`. Try using state-management like riverpod or bloc instead of using global variables in project cases.

As for the solution, I am creating a model class.

```dart
class Task {
  final String text;
  final bool isChecked;

  Task({
    required this.text,
    this.isChecked = false,
  });

  Task copyWith({
    String? text,
    bool? isChecked,
  }) {
    return Task(
      text: text ?? this.text,
      isChecked: isChecked ?? this.isChecked,
    );
  }
}
```

Now the list will be `var toDoList = [Task(text: "")];`

And your `ToDos`

```dart
class ToDos extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Task> list;
  const ToDos({
    Key? key,
    required this.list,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDos> createState() => _ToDosState();
}

class _ToDosState extends State<ToDos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //todo: remove  [StatefulBuilder]
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setStateSB) {
      return Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ToDoColumn(setStateSB),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  //current
  Column ToDoColumn(
    StateSetter setStateSB,
  ) {
    return Column(children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < widget.list.length; i++)
        CheckboxListTile(
          value: widget.list[i].isChecked,
          onChanged: (_value_1) {
            widget.list[i] = widget.list[i].copyWith(isChecked: _value_1);

            setState(() {});
            setStateSB(() {});
          },
          title: Text('${widget.list[i].isChecked}'),
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          checkColor: Colors.black,
        )
    ]);
  }
}
```

More about [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and [cookbook on flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)